# Storing items even after exiting the program, and call them when need it

Tags: java, user-interface

I'm pretty new to java and i didn't really understood how arry works. I got a question regarding storing around 700 items (e-mails) and call them when is need it.

Example:

First GUI: contains tree text fields, one for ID, second for account and third for password

Second GUI: contains one field which serves as caller using the ID of the account

Is this possible to store that amount of items even after closing the program? also to be noted that items store will be used on other application/site

Thanks,
Cristian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays are situated in memory. When the program closes, the memory is freed. You need to write the data to a file, database or other such place to keep it safe between launches of your application.

Comment: I was thinking, isn't possible to store the items into a class and call them from there ?

Comment: If the data is static then you can keep it in the class, but even then it might become cumbersome especially if you need to do modifications to the data.